# npm, bwr versus simple download

Tags: npm, bower

We use to download folders and files and while on the Visual studio we started to use the nuget.  Now when I am working on the angular js, I am seeing bower and npm.  I want to ask are the equivalent to download?  If it is, what benefits they give us? Or they worked after the download?

For example see the below extract from the website.

**via bower:**

$ bower install angular-loading-bar

**via npm:**

$ npm install angular-loading-bar

**via CDN:**

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.7.1/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
```